# Apache Spark image processing using OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, dictionary, apache-spark, processing

I'm trying image processing on `Apache Spark` and I'm using `Python` language

RDD dataset is made image data in local disks

so, I did this :

```
sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName("classification").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf = sparkConf)

ImageRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles("PATH/*.jpg")
```

and ImageRDD may be distributed in several nodes.

from now on, I don't know how to operate imageRDD data with OpenCV.

My plan is that to take each value(image) in imageRDD and use imread(OpenCV function) to convert OpenCV image data.

OpenCV image data features will be extracted, and these features will be new Rdd dataset.

Comment: Here's an example for detecting the face
https://github.com/openreserach/bin2seq/blob/master/src/test/java/com/openresearchinc/hadoop/test/SparkTest.java#L190
you might find it useful.